# Redirect to the same page after registration with WooCommerce/WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, registration

I use the WooCommerce login/registration shortcode [woocommerce_my_account] as a popup on several pages and I like the user to stay on that page after they register.

Signup redirects to the same page and works well, but the default behaviour for the registration is to redirect to the my-account page. I've tried quite a few options in my functions.php but I couldn't get it to work so far.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you mean when user sign in it should stay on the same page right? if yes what message do you want to print there, because after sign in the fields cannot come again and it would redirect to you on my account status page?

Comment: Hi Raj Kumar, Yes the user should stay on the same page because the (on page) popup disappears automatically once the user is logged in so that the content behind the popup shows. Therefore I don't need to print any message.

Comment: can you paste your website link here also if possible show pop up the code?

Comment: The popup is created with Boxzilla and only contains the [woocommerce_my_account] shortcode. It is under construction, but this is the temporary link where you can see it: http://eliv.com.tw/shop/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using session.
On registration/login pop you have to add current link into session variable. And after successfully registration redirect to variable page.
But make sure your redirection must be load after default behaviour.
Hope this helps you. Thanks